# error coming while i am start the yarn.sh

Tags: hadoop-yarn

```
start-yarn.sh
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-ubuntu.out
nice: /bin/yarn: No such file or directory
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-ubuntu.out
localhost: nice: /bin/yarn: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install yarn with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install cmdtest
```

Comment: i tried this command also bt it is showing unable to locate the packet